# Asp.net RDLC report not showing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dataset, rdlc

I have a asp.net project(deployed on remote server) that used rdlc reports to show data, now I have updated the a dataset query and rebuild my project and it runs locally perfectly. Then instead of replacing whole project, I only replace the `userreport.aspx` and `userreport.rdlc` files on the server. Now the issue is the report is loaded but not showing the data. But when I export the rdlc report to excel, word or pdf it contains data but now showing in the report also in view source.

Previously, userreport has 3 files
`userreports.aspx`, `userreport.rdlc` and `userreportdataset.xsd`.
and after building I only replaced `userreports.aspx` and `userreport.rdlc`.

Is there any mistake I have made, unable to track the error.
[image]

Comment: you pushed the .rdlc to the SSRS server or web server?  I believe you have to push it to the SSRS server along with the updated dataset.  In Visual Studio you can publish the rdlc that will push everything it needs to the SSRS box including the dataset.

Comment: it is on the dedicated window server,

Answer (score 0):

Enter this into a Chrome tab:
chrome://net-internals
Click on "Sockets"
Click "Flush Socket Pools"

Also: Clear your cache and browsing data from the beginning of time.

Comment: Source a youtube video